# In CakePHP3 how do I create a custom model rule which validates that a time is after another time in the same table?

Tags: validation, cakephp, orm, model, cakephp-3.0

Columns (both datatype time):

```
Start
End
```

End cannot be before start.

```
    $validator
    ->requirePresence('end', 'create')
        ->notEmpty('end')
        ->add('end', [
                    'time' => [
                            'rule'      => 'time',
                            'message'   => 'end can only accept times.'
                            ],
                    'dependency' => [
                            'rule'  => [$this, 'endBeforeStart'],
                            'message'   => 'end can not be before start.'
                        ],
                ]);
```

If it is a PUT request which only contains end, the model will need to query the existing record to compare against start. If it is a PUT which contains both then it need to validate against the intended new parameter.

How does cakePHP3 do this?

```
private function endBeforeStart($fieldValueToBeValidated, $dataRelatedToTheValidationProcess)
{
//What goes here?
}
```

I can't seem to find any examples of doing this online.

Comment: So what exactly is it that you don't understand? How to query data? How to access the table from your validation rule? How to figure whether the request contains a start date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure and haven't tested it, but maybe this gives you some hints:

```
$validator
->add('end', [
  'endBeforeStart' => [
    'rule' => function ($value, $context) {
      // If it's a POST (new entry):
      if ( $context['newRecord'] == '1' ) {
        // Do your comparison here
        // Input values are e.g. in $context['data']['starttime']
        // If end is before start:
        return false;
      }
      // If it's a PUT (update):
      else {
        // If starttime is not in $context['data']['starttime']
        // check for the old value in $getOldEntry
        $getOldEntry = $this->getOldEntry( $context['data']['id'] );
        // And do your comparison here...
        // If end is before start:
        return false;
      }
      return true;
    },
    'message' => 'end can not be before start.' ],
  ])

public function getOldEntry($id = null) {
  return $this->get($id);
}
```

I'm also not sure if the last function has to be private or public...

Comment: That's great thank you. Marked as the answer as this seems easier than what I was trying to achieve.